# How to pass a callback function with multiple possible parameter lists

Tags: javascript

Here are two callback function:

```
function callback_a(){
  alert('a');
}

function callback_b(p){
  alert('b says'+ p)'
}
```

If I want use `callback_a`

```
function test(callback){
  if(condition){
    callback();
  }
}

test(callback_a);
```

But the function `test` isn't applicable to `callback_b`, So how to implement a common function that you can passing some callbacks function with multiple possible parameter lists.

Comment: Why don't simply call test as following: `test(callback_b('what b has to say'))`

Comment: @malarres It will still execute `callback_b` if the condition equls false

Comment: @malarres: **And** it would execute `callback_b` *first*, before `test`.

Comment: ahhh thanks for clarifying :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a special object called `arguments` that gets created when a function is invoked.  It's an array-like object that represents the arguments passed in to a function:

It can be used like this:

```
test();
  // no arguments passed, but it still gets created:
  // arguments.length = 0
  // arguments >> []

test(a);
  // ONE argument passed:
  // arguments.length = 1
  // arguments >> [a]

test(a,b,c,d);
  // FOUR arguments passed:
  // arguments.length = 4
  // arguments >> [a,b,c,d]
```

Knowing this, one can call a callback with the rest of the arguments passed in from the parent function using `apply` like this:

```
function test(callback) {
  callback.apply(null, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1));
}
// arguments passed into test are available in the function scope when
// .slice is used here to only pass the portion of the arguments
// array relevant to the callback (i.e. any arguments minus the
// first argument which is the callback itself.)
//
// N.B. The arguments object isn't an array but an array like object so
// .slice isn't available on it directly, hence .call was used here)
```

Might be worth reading up on:

- The [arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments)
- [`Function.prototype.apply`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/apply), [`Function.prototype.call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call) and [`Function.prototype.bind`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) as they are way to bind a context ***and*** arguments to a function (**i.e. they'll work with the [arguments object](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments) to call a function where you may not know how many arguments will be passed**)

Comment: This doesn't seem to have much of any connection to the question. The question is about passing different functions into `test` that have different formal parameter lists. The answer is about the number of arguments passed to `test`. How does that even begin to answer the question? Separately, the example at the end is passing `callback` to itself, which seems a strange thing to do, especially given what `callback_b` does with its parameter.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: OP posted: _"how to implement a common function that you can passing some callbacks function with multiple possible parameter lists"_.  I read that as how do they go about handling different callbacks whose arguments list varies and still be able to pass the relevant arguments through to the callbacks.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: agreed that my example is weird, I did initially include the caveat that the 1st argument would be the callback, but i thought that this would be implicit if OP understood the reasoning behind my answer (and therefore handle the argumetns at `test` or `callback` level

Comment: I read it differently, but as the OP has selected this as the right answer, you must have read his/her mind. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: Don't feel bad ;-D, I found yours useful based on the insight it gave me into your reasoning behind writing such a function in-situ within a framework or API.

Comment: As it appears now, the `test` function will call `callback` with the whole list of arguments (including `callback` itself). You need to slice the `arguments` array.

Comment: @meltedspark: in lieu of all the comments about this, I've amended my answer

Comment: @meltedspark: noticed a massive mistake in the updated edit, correct the slice method to use `.call` correctly now... :)

Comment: @Pineda Just curious, why do you call it with `apply`, why not just `arguments.slice(1)`?

Comment: `apply` take the arguments array-like object and invoke the callback with each element as an argument, rather than as an array as the first parameter.  Either will work, calling it directly with arguments.slice(1) would be akin to replacing `apply` with `call` in my case.  Really depends on how one wants to handle the arguments in the callback: as one array, or as individual parameters.

Answer (score 6):

There are three options:

- The easiest way is to use spread operator:

  ```
  function test(callback, ...callback_args) {
    callback(...callback_args);
  }
  ```

  in this case the invocation of `test` for function `callback_b` would be like this:

  ```
  test(callback_b,"b")
  ```
- The second way is using `arguments` which are scoped to any function in JavaScript:

  ```
  function test(callback) {
    callback.apply(null, arguments.slice(1));
  }
  ```

  the invocation of `test` for function `callback_b` would be the same:

  ```
  test(callback_b,"b")
  ```
- Another options is to use partially applied functions. In this case you should define `b_callback` like this (`ES6` syntax):

  ```
  let callback_b = (p) => () => void{
      alert('b says'+ p)'
  }
  ```

  or without `ES6`:

  ```
  function callback_b(p) {
      return function(){
          alert('b says'+ p)'
      }
  }
  ```

  and invoke it like this:

  ```
  test(callback_b("b"))
  ```

Answer (score 2):

> So how to implement a common function that you can passing some callbacks function with multiple possible parameter lists.

Basically, you don't. The function receiving the callback is in charge of what the callback receives as arguments. When you call `Array#forEach`, it's `Array#forEach` that decides what arguments your callback gets. Similarly, `String#replace` defines what it will call its callback with.

Your job is to say what `test` will do, what it will call its callback with. Then it's the job of the person using `test` to write their callback appropriately. For instance: You might document `test` as calling the callback with no arguments. If the caller wants to use `callback_b`, then it's up to them to handle the fact that `callback_b` expects a parameter. There are several ways they can do that:

The could wrap it in another function:

```
test(function() {
    callback_b("appropriate value here");
});
```

...or use `Function#bind`

```
test(callback_b.bind(null, "appropriate value here"));
```

...but it's *their* problem, not yours.

Side note: If they pass you `callback_b` and you call it without any arguments, you won't get an error. JavaScript allows you to call a function with fewer arguments than it expects, or more. How the function handles that is up to the author of the function.

Comment: I'm not sure if it is suitable to call it _callback_. In fact, I just want to make a judgment through `test` before executing `callback_a` or `callback_b` to determine if  them should be executed

Comment: @qslcna: I'm afraid I don't understand your first point above. You're passing `test` a function and calling it; that's a text book callback. Re your second point, you could check the arity of the function you receive by looking at its `length` property. That tells you how many formal parameters it says it accepts, so for instance `function foo(a, b) { }` has `foo.length` of `2`. (But it's complicated; ES2015's rest parameter and default parameters don't show up in the arity of the function.)

Comment: The first point, I mean I don't know if it is suitable to say it is a kind of _callback_ function

Comment: @qslcna: Well, since you're passing a function into `test` and then having `test` call that function, that's pretty much the textbook definition of a callback.

Comment: I see. But I think the function `test` looks more like a kind of wrapper. This is what I want `test` really is.

Comment: @qslcna: *`test`* isn't the callback. The callback is the function you pass *into* `test`. As far as I know, there's no generic term for what `test` is (a function that accepts a callback).

Comment: of course, I certainly know `test` is not the callback :)

Comment: @qslcna: Then I have no idea what you're asking in the comments. :-)

Comment: I want to make sure if the way using `test` as wrapper to judge if the callback function should be executed is right. The callback has no constraint, it maybe any function you want. In this situation should I still use the way of callback?

Comment: @qslcna: Then you do indeed want something very similar to Pineda's answer, but you want to leave `callback` out when you call it: `function test(callback) { if (condition) { callback.apply(null, Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1); } }` Or as of ES2015 (aka "ES6"), it could be `function test(callback, ...args) { if (condition) { callback(...args); } }`

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the parameter while calling the callback

```js
function test(callback){
  if(condition){
    callback();
  }
  else if(other condition){
    callback("b");  
   }
}

test(callback_b);
```

You can write your callback function like

```js
function callback_a_b(){
  if(arguments.length){
    var arg = [].slice.call(arguments);
    alert('b says'+ arg[0])  
  }
  else{
   alert('a');  
  }
  
}
```

Comment: I want use the function `test` in that way, you can both pass `callback_a` and `callback_b` to it and it should work :)

Comment: But that would not work if passing callback_a as the callback function. That's exactly the problem that OP desires to get an answer to.

Comment: @ricky sorry this is not what I want.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an anonymous function as the callback that will itself return your desired callback function with parameters.

```
test(function() { return callback_b(' how are you'); });
```

see this working snippet that will first use callback_a, then callback_b (with parameter) as the callback:

```js
function callback_a(){
  alert('a');
}

function callback_b(p){
  alert('b says'+ p);
}

function test(callback){
  if(true){
    callback();
  }
}

test(callback_a);
test(function() { return callback_b(' how are you'); });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can pass array of parameters as second param of `test` function or in ES6 use spread operator [read more here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator#A_better_apply)

```
function test(callback, params){
  if(condition){
    if (params === undefined){
      callback();
    } else {
      callback.apply(null, params); //params must be array
      //ES6: callback(...params);
    }
  }
}

test(callback_a);
test(callback_b, [" whatever"]);
```

Answer (score 0):

I've just checked in my browser (ffox 51.0.1)  that the following works:

```
function test(callback,other_args){if(condition){callback(other_args);}}
```

results:

- condition=true
- test(callback_a)

  - => shows the alert with 'a'
- condition=false
- test(callback_a)

  - => doesn't show anything
- condition=true
- test(callback_b,"pepe")

  - => shows the alert with 'b sayspepe'
- condition=false
- test(callback_b,"pepe")

  - => doesn't show anything